# scrollTop issue on constant moving div

Tags: javascript

I have a FLASH object that I mouse over which in turn calls the following function to scroll a div.  It works but due to the constant high speed scrolling it would throw up NULLS.  This in turn caused IE to open a new page through my FLASH ActionScript 2.0

I found that by creating the SC variable and throwing in the condition "if it exists" keeps FLASH from causing IE to open a new page.

However, it still creates an error behind the scenes of "Object Required".  Although my application works I do not want load up memory with errors.

Any thoughts?

```
var SC;

function pP(PT){
 SC=document.getElementById('P'+PT).offsetTop;
 if(SC){document.getElementById('CBOX').scrollTop=SC;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you just wrap it with try-catch to swallow error?

```
function pP(PT) {
    try {
        var SC = document.getElementById('P' + PT).offsetTop;
        if(SC) { document.getElementById('CBOX').scrollTop = SC; }
    } catch(e) {}
 }
```